# Javascript change getHours to 2 digit

Tags: javascript

***Historic question. It's now simply:***

```
.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0')
```

---

If the hour is less than 10 hours the hours are usually placed in single digit form.

```
var currentHours = currentTime.getHours ( );
```

Is the following the only best way to get the hours to display as `09` instead of `9`?

```
if (currentHours < 10)  currentHours = '0'+currentHours;
```

Comment: Better ways are: 1) use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and its formatting abilities, 2) use a generic formatting function, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/610406/989121

Comment: With EcmaScript 6: ```new Date().getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');```

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Your's method is good.  Also take a note of it

```
var date = new Date();
currentHours = date.getHours();
currentHours = ("0" + currentHours).slice(-2);
```

Comment: this is too good, even this can be used for minutes as well

Answer (score 18):

You can't do much better. Maybe you'll like:

```
var currentHours = ('0'+currentTime.getHours()).substr(-2);
```

Comment: This is amazing. I have created a custom function based on this.  `get_current_date_time() {
    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
    var currentHours = ('0'+today.getHours()).substr(-2);
    var currentMins = ('0'+today.getMinutes()).substr(-2);
    var currentSecs = ('0'+today.getSeconds()).substr(-2);
    var time = currentHours + ":" + currentMins + ":" + currentSecs;
    var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;
    return dateTime;
  }`

Comment: `substr()` is deprecated, but you can use `slice()` to do the same thing (using a negative number to count from the end).

Answer (score 16):

You can do this using below code,

create function,

```
function addZeroBefore(n) {
  return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
}
```

and then use it as below,

```
c = addZeroBefore(deg);
```

Comment: I like this approach: simple, elegant. Here's how I use it to format time: 
`code -- 
    function nn(n) { 
      return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n; 
    } 
    function getTime(){ 
      var now = new Date();<br/>
      var h = nn(now.getHours()); 
      var m = nn(now.getMinutes()); 
      var s = nn(now.getSeconds()); 
      return [ h, m, s ].join(':'); 
    }`