# DayJS format seconds minutes and hours

Tags: javascript

I want to format `hours minutes seconds` when I get the `diff` value from `dayjs`.

This is my code:

```
    newAppoint.occupied.push({
        hours: dayjs().diff(user.appointment, 'hour'),
        minutes: dayjs().diff(user.appointment, 'minute'),
        seconds: dayjs().diff(user.appointment, 'second')
    });
```

Now the problem is that I get difference like `0 hrs 3 min 228 sec`.

How can I turn that into something like this: `00 hrs 03 min 59 sec`?

I've tried to add this code after the `push` function:

```
    dayjs(newAppoint.occupied.hours).format('hh');
    dayjs(newAppoint.occupied.minutes).format('mm');
    dayjs(newAppoint.occupied.seconds).format('ss');
```

But it doesnt make any difference.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Comment: See this similar question for a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889548/javascript-change-gethours-to-2-digit

Comment: I think you are trying to get hours, min and seconds from dayjs. If so, you are wrong, because it will return the diff in the provided unit, like min or seconds. I think what you need is to just get the seconds by `seconds: dayjs().diff(user.appointment, 'second')` and format the seconds in the desired `hh mm ss` string by using `padStart`

Comment: @iamkhush Yeah. I've also tried to convert seconds only and it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The diff function returns the total number of seconds or minutes or hours rather than the component parts.

Try this:

```
totalSeconds = dayjs().diff(user.appointment, 'second');

totalHours = Math.floor(totalSeconds/(60*60))  // How many hours?
totalSeconds = totalSeconds - (totalHours*60*60) // Pull those hours out of totalSeconds

totalMinutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds/60)  //With hours out this will retun minutes
totalSeconds = totalSeconds - (totalMinutes*60) // Again pull out of totalSeconds
```

you then have three variables with your needed values:`totalHours` `totalMinutes` and `totalSeconds`