# Why are the keys in my string object for a select box being converted to numbers when deploying my Next.js app?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

In next.js app,

I'm using an object of string key and string value in the select box which looks like this:

```
export const HOURS: { [key: string]: string } = {
  '00': '00',
  '01': '01',
  '02': '02',
  '03': '03',
  '04': '04',
  '05': '05',
  '06': '06',
  '07': '07',
  '08': '08',
  '09': '09',
  '10': '10',
  '11': '11',
  '12': '12',
  '13': '13',
  '14': '14',
  '15': '15',
  '16': '16',
  '17': '17',
  '18': '18',
  '19': '19',
  '20': '20',
  '21': '21',
  '22': '22',
  '23': '23',
} as const
```

when I debug it in the local running app, it's just fine (it prints out the object as it was defined)

but in a bundled & deployed application, the key of the object is automatically converted as number, which makes the sorted order of the select box different from the desired output. ('00' becomes 0 and '01' becomes 1 so the order is not same comparing it to the local application)

```js
0: "00",
1: "01",
2: "02"
...
```

is there any way to fix it and preserve the key as it is declared?

i tried defining types `{ [key: string]: string }` 
and declaring as `as const` but not working

Comment: check SWC minify options in config https://nextjs.org/docs/architecture/nextjs-compiler

Comment: As a side note you shouldn't be relying on object properties for sort order.

Answer (score 1):

as Denris [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/840563/dennis-liger)
it's because of swc config option, you can turn it off in next.config.js by setting:
swcMinify: false,

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not rely on object sorting order, it is not guaranteed.
Better to use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for this. It will solve your problem.

If to go further:
I saw that you named your object HOURS and could assume that you are working with time. And the real goal of your object is only to add zero to single digit value. There are multiple other ways to set time format depending on your particular implementation and date formatting syntax. Or primitive way here [Javascript change getHours to 2 digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889548/javascript-change-gethours-to-2-digit) or here https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-get-minutes-with-leading-zero